# C array of strings referenced by const GLchar **

Tags: c, swig

I have a C function that requires to be called with a `const GLchar **` parameter.

I am not a C programmer by trade (Perl is my game) but I am trying to call a C library from Perl. I have all the other required functions wrapped (SWIG). This is the last troublesome one.
Please don't shoot me down for my (lack of) C skills. I am trying and Google only helps if you know exactly what to type!

I understand that `const GLchar **` means that it wants a pointer to an array of strings (`GLchar` arrays).
With no way of creating that directly I have to create a `GLchar` array first:

```
    GLbyte *GLbyte_array(int size) {
      return (GLbyte *) malloc(sizeof(GLbyte)*size);
    }
```

So I use that in Perl via:

```
    my $var=GLbyte_array(20);
```

and then populate that one `char` at a time from Perl by calling:

```
   void GLbyte_put(GLbyte *a, int i, char val) {
     a[i] = val;
   }
```

Again, Perl:

```
    my $str="hello";
    for(my $i; $i<length($str); $i++)
    { GLbyte_put($var, $i); }
```

All good. (well, perhaps not good - but it works).
I have a C char array containing the word "hello".

My solution then was to attempt to build an array of these guys and drop the array I created above into it. Then return my required pointer to it:

```
    const GLchar **get_GLbyte_array_ptr(GLbyte *a) {
     char *arr[1];
     arr[0]= a;
     return (const GLchar**)arr[0];
   }
```

Perl:

```
    my $ptr=get_GLbyte_array_ptr($var);
```

This is clearly a load of tosh. It compiles and then segfaults.

Can you recommend alternate code/fixes for the problem?

Comment: First of all, array concept is just an abstraction of the C pointers. So int** var; is a pointer to a pointer that points an integer.

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı - i tried what you suggested with the &, but it gives me the same segfault. thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @netcoder - it segfaults when i call the function which uses the "const GLchar**" that i think i have created. which for completeness is a "glShaderSource($shader, 1, $ptr , undef);". If i was calling this from C, i could probably just use &ptr at this time, but i dont have the luxury of being able to cast at runtime, i have to pass the function the exact type it is expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather than

```
return (const GLchar**)arr[0];
```

could you try this:

```
return (const GLchar**)&arr;
```

Comment: i tried what you said which WAS one step in the right direction. then i realised that my "const GLchar**" was being declared locally. added "static" to it, and hey presto...working like a charm. many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

final version looked like this:

```
    const GLchar **get_GLbyte_array_ptr(GLbyte *a) {
    static char *arr[1];
    arr[0]= a;
    return (const GLchar**)&arr;
    }
```